# How are we supposed to report low quality posts if we cannot use the "Flag"

Tags: discussion, flagging

I keep getting my flags rejected like this:

> very low quality – Eric 2 days ago   declined - flags should only be
>   used to make moderators aware of content that requires their
>   intervention

If we are not supposed to use flags for low quality content then how do we report it?

For the record the answer flagged was:

[How to query More than 50000 records from sObject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102030/how-to-query-more-than-50000-records-from-sobject/102036#102036)

And it was a completely incorrect answer

Comment: I believe this might turn in to a discussion about the difference between LVQ (very low quality) versus NAA (not an answer) flags. Perhaps the reviewer that declined your flag felt NAA would be more appropriate than LVQ, even though the net result would probably have been the same-- deletion of the incorrect answer. It's entirely possible that the reviewer might have even expected a delete flag instead. This is a great question, but I suspect it's more subtle than you might think.

Comment: There is no option for delete when clicking the flag button. But it is an answer just low quality. Lol. See u right as always

Comment: It's to the left of flag (share edit delete flag). See [the help topic](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) regarding deleted answers. It only appears once an answer reaches -1, unless you're the author.

Comment: Ok. It does not show for me on that specific answer so....

Comment: See [How does deleting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221). I just realized you probably don't have the rep to flag deletes ("Users with reputation ≥ 20k ... may also delete answers of score −1 or lower."). You'll get there soon. That seems like a pretty high bar to reach considering there's only five of us on the network that can do so (besides moderators).

Comment: I didn't realized so much rep was needed for that either. Rep caps were 50% during beta.

Comment: A lot of the caps for privileges and badges seem a bit high for this site imo. We are relatively low volume.

Comment: good thing I'm more than 7500 rep points away from 20K as otherwise I'd be mashing the keyboard with the  "you've got to be kidding, not another one of these 'write my code for me' or 'can you read my mind' questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I did that.** I wouldn't mind changing my behavoir if there's a shared demand from the community to do so.

My reasoning so far has been that flags are a direct line to moderators and should mainly be used for cases that require ASAP intervenience or to execute actions only performable by moderators (eg:convert to comment, certification question answers, abusive spam, "social misconduct",  ...).

While we're active, I do not believe we should become a bottleneck for certain actions that can be performed by the community itself. **It's the community empowerment that we want to enlarge**, not the moderation team or moderation time.

flag description:

> **very low quality**
>
> and might need to be removed.> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question
> is unlikely to be salvageable through editing,

**For low quality or incorrect answers I believe the first actions should primarily be to down vote and to comment or edit the answer**. Not to delete or have it removed.  It both contributes context to the question to know what are invalid approaches and educates the person providing the answer why they were wrong. That may even motivate them to pursue the real answer and yet update their answer.

In contrast: New questions, thank you comments or "did you fix this ?" answers do not contribute in anyway and should be removed as answers. By members of the community or moderators.

**On community empowerment: Vote!** support others for their contributions and keep in mind the [privileges](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that come with reputation.

Comment: On the same note "I did that". I will stop as well if needed. I was under the impression that flagging was what put the answer into the queue for review in the low quality. I understand what you are saying about incorrect answers but some are just plain wrong and there are a lot of people who do not understand why it was down voted and do not read comments but will try the answer. It perpetuates bad practices.

Comment: I believe the low quality queue is only populated by automatic scripts, not by the flags.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the discussion. I will not use it anymore then

Comment: Hold on - I was incorrect: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/192215  - based on that I could as well ignore them when I disagree and leave them to the reviewers to deal with if they are indeed added to the relevant queues.

Comment: Interesting......